# NetScaler rewrite - avoid SSL certificate check for old domain

Tags: ssl, url-rewriting, netscaler

Goal: using NetScaler, have https://OLDDOMAIN rewritten to https://NEWDOMAIN before the SSL check for OLDDOMAIN.com happens (and fails).

Edit:
Answer: can't be done. See clarifying comment below (thanks).

Comment: maybe because the NEWDOMAIN VIP uses SSL offloading, it can't be done on that VIP? maybe using a separate VIP for OLDDOMAIN that does not have SSL offload active would work?

Comment: In short: redirect happens *after* the SSL handshake and thus *after* the certificate validation so there is no way to redirect before the certificate validation takes place.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Much appreciated.